# VBA - Nested Class

Tags: ms-access, vba

[Edited the code]
Sorry for newbie question.  I was trying to test nested classes in VBA for Excel but got error message.  Can anyone help me understand why?  Thank you!

Inside class:

```
' CLASS MODULE - cInside
' Member variables
Private m_Value As Integer

' Properties
Property Get Value() As Integer
    Value = m_Value
End Property

Property Let Value(i As Integer)
    m_Value = i
End Property

' Methods
Sub init()
    m_Value = 0
End Sub

Sub Inc()
    m_Value = m_Value + 1
End Sub
```

Outside class:

```
' CLASS MODULE - cOutside
' Member variables
Private m_Num1 As New cInside
Private m_Num2 As New cInside

' Properties
Property Get Num1() As cInside
    Num1 = m_Num1.Value
End Property

Property Get Num2() As cInside
    Num2 = m_Num2.Value
End Property

Property Set Num1(i As cInside)
    Set m_Num1 = i
End Property

Property Set Num2(i As cInside)
    Set m_Num2 = i
End Property
```

Main program:

```
Sub Main()

Dim o As New cOutside
Dim i As New cInside

i.Value = 9
i.Inc
Debug.Print i.Value '<-- this works

Set o.Num1 = i
o.Num1.Inc  '<-- object variable or with block variable not set
Debug.Print (o.Num1.Value)

End Sub
```

Thank you again!

Comment: You don't have a `Inc` method defined for your `cOutside` class - are you assuming it's going to pull from `cInside`? You have `Init` defined for both.

Comment: @dbmitch, how shall I fix this problem?  If I have multiple layer of nested class, do I have to define the same method in each layer?  Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n.Num1` returns an `Integer`, which isn't an instance of `cInside`, and therefore doesn't have an `Inc` member, which makes it an *invalid qualifier* for the compiler to complain about ;-)

Your `cOutside` class needs to expose it somehow:

```
Property Get ComposedObject1() As cInside
    Set ComposedObject1 = m_Num1
End Property
```

Then the calling code could do this:

```
n.ComposedObject1.Inc
```

I called that "composed", because what you're doing isn't "nesting", but "composition". VBA doesn't supported nested classes, which would be a class module defined inside another class module, like so:

```
Class Outside
    '... members...

    Class Inside
        '...members...
    End Class
End Class
```

VB.NET can do that, but in VBA 1 class module can only define 1 class.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  As a newbie, I was wondering how Excel VBA object works.  For example, a workbook object contains worksheets objects, which contain range objects.  Then I was able to do something like wb.ws.rng.values.  Does that mean the "values" property has to be defined in each class?  Thank you!

Comment: `wb.ws.rng` wouldn't be legal. Assuming `wb` is a `Workbook` instance, then `wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value` would be more like it - anyway no, the dot (`.`) denotes a *member call*, which means the member being invoked needs to be defined in the *type* (that's the class) of the expression that comes before the dot. In the case of `Range("A1").Value`, `Value` is a member of the `Range` class, and `Range` is (confusingly, perhaps) a member of the `Worksheet` class that returns an instance of the `Range` class. Find the classes in the object browser (F2) for everything you need to know =)

Comment: @Mathiew, I edited the code and got a different error "object variable or with block variable not set".  Can yo please take a look?  Thanks!

Comment: You missed the `Set` keyword, which is required when assigning object references.

Comment: Edited the code again.  Now we're moving one step forward.  But get the error on the next line of code.  :)

Comment: Compare yout getter to mine

Comment: Finally got it.  Much appreciate it!  Mathiew